# Located a cell in the row following the last row and set a formula for an adjacent cell to equal it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my script. I am using this to locate the last row in my spreadsheet and then place data in the row below it. My problem is that I need the script to look at that row and determine what row number it is so that I can use that calculation to solve a following column.

More precisely, I will place text in columns a-e of the lastrow+1. Column F will be left blank. I want to put a formula in column G that says =column F, so that once data is entered in F it will also be in column G. It needs to continously work as more cells placed at the bottom of the spreadsheet by running the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function MH484020() {

    //Grab the active spreadsheet

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    //Find the first last row with data in it

    var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

    //Use the last row with data in it to place forumulas below it

    var range = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,2);
    range.setValue('DRAINAGE STR. 48-4020')

    var range = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3)
    range.setValue('484020')

    //Set data validation for steps or not

    var range = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,4);
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Yes','No'])
    .build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);

    //Use the last row with data in it to place forumula for covers calculation

    var range = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,6);
    return range;
    sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,7).setFormula("=range");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,7).setFormula("=F" + (lastrow+1));
```

instead of:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,6);
    return range;
    sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,7).setFormula("=range");
```

Edit:
How would you change that in order to reference multiple cells in the formula? I need to say Column H = Column E - (Column F x 1.5)

```
sheet.getRange("H" + (lastrow+1))
  .setFormula("=E" + (lastrow+1) + "-(F" + (lastrow+1) + "*1.5)");
```

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate the help. I am just getting into scripting for the first time.

Comment: How would you change that in order to reference multiple cells in the formula? I need to say Column H = Column E - (Column F x 1.5)

Comment: I'll probably get in trouble for answering this here. Compound questions are frowned upon. In the future please ask anew.